# Как поменять TTL в Windows 10 Feature Update 2004?

Tags: windows, сеть

После чистой установки новой версии Windows 10 (у меня сборка 19041.329) перестал работать ключ реестра DefaultTTL.
Обнаружено командой `ping 127.0.0.1`.
При этом в Wireshark видно, что ICMP Request имеет ttl такой, как указано в DafaultTTL, а ICMP Replay имеет стандартный ttl - 128.
Разумеется, перезагрузку выполнял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока не понятно, что именно случилось. Судя по всему, в версии 2004 что-то сильно поменялось.
По крайней мере, следующие команды работают как раньше:

```
netsh int ipv4 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=<value>
netsh int ipv6 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=<value>
```

Лично мне даже не пришлось перезагружаться.